# Retrieve array from Parse.com

Tags: ios, arrays, database, nsarray, parse-platform

I want to retrieve an array from Parse.com. The array is saved in the user class in Parse, and I would like to retrieve only the array linked to the current user.

I know this code is not valid, but I think it illustrates exactly what I want:

```
NSArray *array = [[PFUser currentUser] arrayForKey:@"arrayKey"];
```

I know this code snippet might seem stupid for some of you, but I hope you get what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PFUser* currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
NSArray* myArray = currentUser[@"arrayKey"];
```